# Clojure: a function that removes a given node from a collection

Tags: clojure

I'd like to have a function that removes any node (sub-collection) from a collection containing that node.

```
(def coll {:a ["b" {:c "d" :e ["f" {:g "h"}]}]})
(def node {:g "h"})
```

What would be a good remove-node function?

```
(remove-node coll node)
;=> {:a ["b" {:c "d" :e ["f"]}]})
```

Thanks!

EDIT :
What I want to do is delete an enlive-node

```
(def enlive-node
  [{:type :dtd, :data ["html" nil nil]} 
   {:tag :html, 
    :attrs nil, 
    :content ["\n" 
              {:tag :head, 
               :attrs nil, 
               :content ["\n    \n    " 
                         {:tag :title, 
                          :attrs nil, 
                          :content ["Stack Overflow"]} 
                         "\n    " 
                         {:tag :link, 
                          :attrs {:href "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico", 
                                  :rel "shortcut icon"}, 
                                  :content nil}]}]}])
```

The node to remove is always a string or an *entire* hash-map.

```
(remove-node enlive-node {:tag :title, 
                              :attrs nil, 
                              :content ["Stack Overflow"]})
```

Comment: Do you have a better coll?

Comment: What's the expected output for `(remove-node coll {:c "d"})`? Does return `{:a ["b"]}` or just an exact copy of `coll`?

Comment: How comes this coll into existence? If I may ask.

Comment: @DaoWen I don't think `{:c ["d"]}` is considered a node of coll.

Comment: @Igrapenthin I added a better coll. It is actually what Enlive produces.

Comment: @DaoWen Good question. There's a risk of removing the wrong node if I just remove say {:tag :div} without having the :attrs nor the :content values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you have, you can use `clojure.walk/postwalk` to walk the hashmap and remove the node.

```
(require '[clojure.walk :as walk])

(defn remove-node [coll target]
  (walk/postwalk
    (fn [item]
      (if (vector? item)
        (filterv #(not= target %) item)
        item))
    coll))

(remove-node coll node)
```

**EDIT:**

From you updated question, it looks like you are operating on an Enlive node collection. An additional solution, in your case, would be to generate an Enlive node selector and transform the collection using the `net.cgrand.enlive-html/at*` function.

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as e])

(defn gen-transform [target]
  [[(cond
     (string? target) e/text-node
     (map? target) (:tag target)
     :else e/any-node)]
   #(when (not= target %) %)])

(defn remove-node [coll & nodes]
  (e/at* coll (map gen-transform nodes)))

(remove-node enlive-node
             {:tag :title, :attrs nil, :content ["Stack Overflow"]}
             "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks! Using with enlive, we just need change `(if (vector? item)` by `(if (seq? item)`

Comment: If you are already using Enlive, why not use `net.cgrand.enlive-html/at` and transform it using the enlive selector syntax and transformations?

Comment: I could if I had the selector. In my particular use case, I don't necessarily know where in the collection, the node is located...

Comment: That sounds like an interesting problem. Try this: https://gist.github.com/Jared314/6618903